# Visual Studio 2013 and C# - Unable to add event handler

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am working on WPF project, and after I made everything in Xaml file I wanted to start doing on my CS file.
Now, I was trying to add event using that little bolt in properties, but everytime i click on any event (for example I select button in XAML and try to add -> MyButton_Click) i get a pop-up message "UNABLE TO ADD EVENT HANDLER".

I hope you are able to help me.

Comment: You probably screwed something up, like renaming the window class incorrectly.  Create a new one with the correct name in the correct namespace, then add your event.

Comment: Try restarting Visual Studio.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

yes, @will is right, I also suffered from the same problem,when i was new in WPF. Please check your x:Class in your XAML file, it should include the namespace used in code behind.
e.g.,
    x:Class="MainWindow"
should be some thing like 
    x:class="namespace.MainWindow"
if it doesn't work,try to restart the VS or try to recreate the project with correct name, hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

I suffered from the same problem like you. Error occurs when you have **any** syntax error in your XAML file like misspell, missing tag, comma, lack of method/event handler or difficulties with references.

Exactly the same reason is when you are unable to add event or change any property in Property Window, but without any message or error. Check your syntax carefully.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

yes. I also face this problem, I fixed it. the problem is on x:Class="MainWindow". just like @Abdullah Said.

Comment: This could have been a comment on the corresponding answer, but in itself as an additional answer it does not seem to add anything.

Answer (score 0):

I had wrong namespace in XAML file after copying/pasting the code. Namespace in XAML and underlaying code must match.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if a method already exists in the .cs file whose name is identical to the method name the IDE is attempting to create.

Answer (score 0):

Once I added a name to the button, I was able to double click it the error went away, opening the code view to the event handler.